# WordPress Navigation Menu Breakpoint issue on Desktop Laptop & Tablet Landscape

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, navigation, header

I am trying to make the navigation menu work responsively on my Wordpress website and am having the following issues:

I have a a two column header, 50/50 boxed structure - left hand side is the logo and RH side is the navigation menu.

I have added the following breakpoints in the site settings:

Mobile portrait - 767px
Mobile landscape - 880px
Tablet portrait - 1400px
Tablet landscape - 1200px
Laptop - 1366px
Widescreen - 2400px

- The hamburger kicks in for the following breakpoints:
  Mobile portrait - 767px
  Mobile landscape - 880px
  Tablet portrait - 1400px
- The navigation menu shows the full menu perfectly on:
  Widescreen - 2400px
- For the following breakpoints, the menu goes onto two lines and loses all styling
  Tablet landscape - 1200px
  Laptop - 1366px

Please can you help with why the tablet landscape and laptop breakpoints are doing this to the navigation menu? And what I could try to resolve these issues?

There is no custom coding carried out on this header - using the Wordpress GUI only

I have tried increasing the width of the navigation bar column, which hasn't resolved the problem

I have also tried recreating a new header which also hasn't worked